# Powerpoint VBA dont close Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

My VBA code in Powerpoint wont "kill" my excel application.
it still runs if i have a look in task manager.

I would like to close it the right way rather than kill.

Anyone that could help me? I already searched and tried to get it working but with no luck.

```
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = 2 Then

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWorkBook As Object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\ELE_powerpoint\book1.xlsx", True, False)

    With xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet
    txt1 = xlWorkBook.sheets(1).Range("A2")
    txt2 = xlWorkBook.sheets(1).Range("A3")
    txt3 = xlWorkBook.sheets(1).Range("A4")
    End With

    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("a2").TextFrame.TextRange = txt1
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("a3").TextFrame.TextRange = txt2
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("a4").TextFrame.TextRange = txt3

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `xlApp.Quit` will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Set xlApp = Nothing
> ```

That instruction sets the `xlApp` object reference to `Nothing`. It doesn't destroy the object it's referring to, but it prevents further code from using *that* reference.

Excel is a rather complex application; creating an instance of an `Excel.Application` object has many implications, and in order to properly shut itself down, it needs to run through a certain sequence of instructions (unload Excel and COM add-ins, close any opened file, tear down the VBE if it was initialized - which in turn may need to tear down its own add-ins, etc.) - by setting your reference to `Nothing`, you say "I don't need it anymore" - but what of the COM add-ins that still use it? That workbook that's still open is a `Workbook` object with an `Application` property that also references the very same object you were referring to - and *these* references aren't gone yet!

As [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102343/powerpoint-vba-dont-close-excel#comment73286589_43102343) and [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43102523/1188513) said, you need to call the `Quit` method of the `Excel.Application` instance, so that it can clean itself up.

And if that's the last thing your code does, then you probably don't even need to `Set xlApp = Nothing`, since the VBA runtime will know that it doesn't need to hold on to the `xlApp` reference after it's out of scope; `Set xlWorkbook = Nothing` is superfluous as well.

Quitting Excel will close the unmodified workbook you've opened, but since *you* opened it, I'd argue that it's good form to close it yourself - just call `xlWorkbook.Close` before you call `xlApp.Quit`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `xlApp.Quit` before `Set xlApp = Nothing`